# Video card driver problems

Tags: drivers

So I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit, put it on a flash drive with unetbootin, and installed it on my PC by itself no dual boot. Then I went on the and site and downloaded the catalyst 13.1 driver pack for Linux 64 bit for my radeon HD 3850, I unzipped it, made it executable, and ran it. But every time I install it or any other driver (I also tried the binary at I xorg driver from the software center) after I restart and login it goes to a screen with nothing but a wallpaper and my cursor. The only way to fix that that I found is to reinstall ubuntu. Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Install the Catalyst driver via *Software & Updates* &rarr; *Additional drivers*. Select `fglrx-updates`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try all of these: [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) ?
One of them caused a log-in loop, so be prepared to get out of a log-in loop.

Comment: A reinstall from live cd-iso "try me" may work; it worked for a desktop I tried upgrading on.